# How to use Eureka Names with OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-eureka

I am using OAuth2RestTemplate in order to pass an oauth token with REST requests. However, I now need to hardcode my urls, such as

```
restTemplate.postForLocation("http://localhost:5555/other-service2/message", "Message")
```

whereas when I was using a self created Ribbon Annotated(using @LoadBalanced) RestTemplate bean, I can do something like

```
 restTemplate.postForLocation("http://service1/other-service2/message", "Message")
```

This is because when you use LoadBalanced, it will automatically make it a Ribbon Rest Template which lets you use the Service Discovery features or Eureka, but when you annotate a OAuth2RestTemplate bean with @Loadbalanced, it would throw some sort of error at runtime when trying to use the OAuth2RestTemplate, which says

```
  o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class java.lang.IllegalStateException, No instances available for localhost
```

My OAuth2RestTemplate creation looks like

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(final UserInfoRestTemplateFactory factory) {
    final OAuth2RestTemplate userInfoRestTemplate = factory.getUserInfoRestTemplate();
    return userInfoRestTemplate;
}
```

How can I use the Service Discovery features as well as load balancing features of Eureka's Ribbon, on an OAuth2RestTemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is something you might try.

In my project we also use OAuth2, Eureka, Ribbon for microservices to communicate each other. In order to use Ribbon with OAuth2, the approach we took was bit different.

First we leave the restTemplate untouched.

```
  @LoadBalanced
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
```

However, we created FeignClientIntercepter implementing RequestIntercepter which sets authorization tokens for OAuth when making a request via restTemplate.

```
  @Component
  public class UserFeignClientInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE = "Jwt";

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
      SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
      Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

      if (authentication != null && authentication
          .getDetails() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication
          .getDetails();
        template.header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER,
            String.format("%s %s", BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE, details.getTokenValue()));
      }
    }
  }
```

And If you try to create spring msa project, I would prefer using **Feign-client** rather than restTemplate.

```
@FeignClient("your-project-name")
public interface YourProjectClient {

  @GetMapping("your-endpoint")
  JsonObject getSomething();
```

Comment: Excellent, will test out when i get to work tomorrow but it seems like a viable solution so accepted

Comment: Hmm.. It actually seems that the requests are not getting intercepted. Was there anything else I needed to change or toggle on?

Comment: Do I need to tag all my endpoints with those feign @FeignClient("endpoint") annotations?

Comment: I`m sorry to check your question late. Tomorrow, I will give you more detail examples.

Comment: Awesome I'll give it a shot at work sometime and give feedback!